# Can I use Regex to return a value based on a specific match?

Tags: regex

If I have a list of addresses related to a specific city for a given company/entity, can I use regex to return that address to me vs doing it in code (db query)? For instance if I have:

```
Manhattan|600 Broadway, 10023|
San Francisco|100 Taylor Street, 94133|
```

Can I have some regex with namegroups that returns that address something along the lines of

```
(?<LOCATION_CITY>Manhattan)(?<LOCATION_BUILDING>600 Broadway)?|(?<LOCATION_CITY2>San Francisco)(?<LOCATION_BUILDING2>100 Taylor)?
```

I get that that is not the correct regex but as a starting point I am wondering if I can use one matched namegroup in the scanned text block to return a known value that is not in the text block. The result I'd be looking for is:

- LOCATION_CITY: Manhattan
- LOCATION_BUILDING: 600 Broadway

or

- LOCATION_CITY: San Francisco
- LOCATION_BUILDING: 100 Taylor Street

Where Location City is returned because it is found in the text  and LOCATION_ADDRESS is returned because the associated city was  found.

Comment: This is a DB query..in which case, what software (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)?

Comment: Are your location city and location building in pair separated by `|`? Example: `LOCATION_CITY1|LOCATION_BUILDING1|LOCATION_CITY2|LOCATION_BUILDING2|`

Comment: @Sam it is MySql however I am looking to be able to just modify/add regex without adding code to the site. The regex are already set up to be called by the site and return grabbed value (LOCATION_CITY) but looking to achieve the returned address in the regex itself.

Comment: @heroandtn3 I can pair/arrange the city and address anyway that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(?<LOCATION_CITY>[^|]+)\|(?<LOCATION_BUILDING>[^|,]+)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that cuts it again the City will be a known value that is being looked for in a block of text and depending on the city that is found the address just needs to be pushed. I'm trying to avoid finding a city and then querying the db.